# bundle error on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundler

This is the error log, when i use `bundle install`.

I want to construct a blog in Github, so use Octopress, but it was unsuccessful. If you have another method, please tell me, thank you.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `"/Applications/Xcode', needed by `redcloth_attributes.o'.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/zb/bxbkz6pd5fscs29zq2hk1b4h0000gn/T/bundler20141230-81071-q2p8fv/RedCloth-4.2.9/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/zb/bxbkz6pd5fscs29zq2hk1b4h0000gn/T/bundler20141230-81071-q2p8fv/RedCloth-4.2.9/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Construct a blog in Github ?! Github is not a free hosting for blogs.

Comment: @Raptor You can host pages on Github. Read: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

Comment: You can host pages like Read Me & change logs, but not a **blog**.

Comment: @Raptor Directly from Github itself: *"they’re also a great way to host your Jekyll-powered website for free."* You can absolutely host a blog on Github, if you want to.

Answer (score 26):

This fixed the issue for me.

```
xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

Comment: This saved me. Looked all over for the answer and it was hiding with no upvotes!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Worked on Big Sur

Answer (score 5):

It looks like maybe your Mac doesn't have xcode command line tools installed. Try this in the terminal then try bundling again:

`xcode-select --install`

You will also need to accept the license agreement. I think it asks you automatically now.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was there is a space in Xcode name

So I rename the "Xcode 13.1" to "Xcode13.1"

Change the developer tools path using xcode-select switch command

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode13.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

Occur same issue after run `sudo gem install cocoapods` on my new m1 macbook pro.

↓This fix issue for me too.

`xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

if you doesn't have CommandLineTools folder, just run `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

**1-st idea:**

Install (update) ruby:

```
brew install ruby
```

And don't forget:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**2-nd idea:**

Maybe you have to install current (compatible to your XCode) 'Command line tools for XCode'. Google for appropriate Version (if your XCode 11.3 so CommandLineToolsForXcode_11.3).